# Robust standard errors (White) under homoscedasticity

Tags: regression, standard-error, covariance-matrix, robust-standard-error, white-test

Robust standard errors (White standard errors) are given by:
$$\hat{V}(b)=(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2x_ix_i')(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$

This helps us to estimate a asymptotic covariance matrix under heteroscedasticity.
Now assume a homoscedastic model, thus $e_i\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $e_i$ is $iid$.
Can the estimator from above be used under these homoscedastic assumptions? How can the equivalance between this estimator and the 'classic' estimator $\hat{V}(b)=\sigma^2(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$ be shown?

Comment: What I know this far is that $E(e_i^2)=\sigma^2$. Thus we can rewrite the White standard errors as:

$$\hat{V}(b)= \sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2 (\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$

But I haven't been able to show asymptotic equivalance to the 'classic' estimator.

My only try to go on was multipling this by $N/N$ which asymptotically (!) yields:
$$\hat{V}(b)=E(e_i^2) (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}=\sigma^2 (\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$

But this doesnt help me either.

Comment: Another comment which might be helpful. I was able to show that:

$$S=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2 x_ix_i'$$ is a consistent estimator for $$\Sigma=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2 x_ix_i'$$. 

If (??) we can assume that from this also follows $$S_{new}=\sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2 x_ix_i'$$ is a consistent estimator for $$\Sigma_{new}=\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2 x_ix_i'$$. 
We might be able to show equivalence.

Comment: Considering the above comment we could take the probability limit (plim) of $$\hat{V}(b)=(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^N e_i^2x_ix_i')(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$
and we'd get
$$plim \hat{V}(b)=(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i^2x_ix_i')(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$ and because of homoscedasticity assumption also
$$plim \hat{V}(b)= \sigma^2(\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i')^{-1}$$